# Android biometric verification - how to get a unique user id?

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I am looking at incorporating `android.hardware.biometrics` classes in my Android application. I need a way to associate a unique id for the given user based on the biometric signature. Is there anything in `BiometricPrompt` fields that I can use to identify the user uniquely?

Obviously, the user id cannot change on each biometric scan. Regards.

Comment: Not sure if you've seen: https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth but realize that biometric auth on Android is bound to the device/app/single user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on using OS-level user accounts (e.g., Settings > System > Multiple Users on a Pixel 6), it's possible they could each have enrolled fingerprints — I have never experimented with this. Each user would have independent internal and external storage, though, so you would create your own unique ID, such as generating a UUID and storing it in internal storage.

If, instead, you were planning on having a more traditional single-user phone setup, but still have N people register fingerprints on that phone and somehow tell them apart... Android's biometrics system does not support that. You would need to use an external fingerprint sensor and its SDK.

Comment: is there a documentation to do this?. my thought approach is in my android application i also have to do biometric registration, then onauthentication success method i have to get some kind of data from the response and i could tie that data for each user..

Comment: @zxc: "then onauthentication success method i have to get some kind of data from the response and i could tie that data for each user" -- that scenario is covered in my second paragraph. What you want is not supported by Android itself, and you would need to use an external fingerprint sensor and its SDK.